# Cannot create X509Certificate2 on mono stack from byte[]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, x509certificate

I am trying to create a certificate (X509Certificate2) from a byte array received in a http response within a Xamarin forms app.  The problem I have is that the constructor of the certificate is throwing an exception.

The code is:

```
public X509Certificate2 GetEmbeddedCertificate(byte[] cred, SecureString password)
{
     return new X509Certificate2(cred, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
}
```

and this is throwing the exception:

```
{System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Undefined length encoding.
at Mono.Security.ASN1..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x0005c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security/ASN1.cs:82 
at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.X509/X509Certificate.cs:111 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00352] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.X509/X509Certificate.cs:211 
at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.X509/X509Certificate.cs:229 
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs:481 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs:490 
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.Security.SecureString password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs:514 
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData, System.Security.SecureString password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs:102
```

I tried performing the certificate construction in native java code (for android) and came across a similar problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495875/java-lang-runtimeexception-error0d0680a8asn1-encoding-routinesasn1-check-tle)

What I am looking for is any way to get this certificate for use in future http requests.

Comment: Sounds like a certificate bytes issue.

Comment: First of all, you must make sure that you receive the right content from the web server. Try saving the file to your local and share the first 32-64 bytes here as seen in a hex editor.. The code is complaining about the 2nd byte of the content for now.

Comment: yet if I use the same code with the same data, built on a full .net stack rather than mono, it works fine...